# Promoted Links and New Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links, new-experience

I have a "promoted links" list that has one view.. Tile.

I also have a New Experience page.  When designing this page I have added a list preview widget, from which I am provided many lists that I can enable, however my promoted links list does not show up as an option.

Why does the list preview not show as an option for designers when building a New Experience page?

Answer (score 0):

You may check below cdb-promoted-links webpart.

https://github.com/CloudDesignBox/cdb-promoted-links